# expected unidentified id before 'if"

Tags: programming, c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char board[3][3]={{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};
char turn='X';
int draw=0;
int row,column;
void display_board()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n\n TIC TAC TOE GAME:";
    cout<<"\n\n PLAYER[1]==O\t\t\t PLAYER[2]==X";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t   "<<board[0][0]<<" |  "<<board[0][1]<<"  |  "<<board[0][2]<<"   \n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t_____|_____|_____\n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t  "<<board[1][0]<<"  |  "<<board[1][1]<<"  |  "<<board[1][2]<<"    \n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t_____|_____|_____\n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t  "<<board[2][0]<<"  |  "<<board[2][1]<<"  |   "<<board[2][2]<<"  \n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t     |     |     \n";
}
void player_turn()
{
    int choice;
    if(turn=='X')
    {
        cout<<"\n\t  PLAYER[1]==O's turn";
    }
    if(turn=='O')
    {
        cout<<"\n\t  PLAYER[2]==X's turn";
    }
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:row=0; column=0; break;
        case 2:row=0; column=1; break;
        case 3:row=0; column=2; break;
        case 4:row=1; column=0; break;
        case 5:row=1; column=1; break;
        case 6:row=1; column=2; break;
        case 7:row=2; column=0; break;
        case 8:row=2; column=1; break;
        case 9:row=2; column=2; break;
        default:
        cout<<"Invalid input";
        break;
    }
   if(turn=='X' && board[row][column]!='X' && board[row][column]!='O')
   { 
       board[row][column]=='X';
       turn='O';
   }
   else if(turn=='O' && board[row][column]!='X' && board[row][column]!='O')
   { 
       board[row][column]=='O';
       turn='X';
   }
   else
   {
       cout<<"Box already filled!\nplease try again!!";
       player_turn();
   }
   display_board();
}
int gameover()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][0]==board[i][2] || board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[0][i]==board[2][i])
        return 0;
        else if(board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[0][0]==board[2][2] || board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[0][0]==board[2][2])
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j]!='X' && board[i][j]!='O')
            return 1;
        }
    }
    draw=1;

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    system("cls");
    while(gameover())
    {
    display_board();
    player_turn();
    gameover();
    }
    return 0;
}


if(turn=='X' && draw=0)
{
    cout<<"PLAYER[2] WINS!!!";
}
else if(turn=='O' && draw==0)
{
    cout<<"PLAYER[1] WINS!!!";
}
else
{
    cout<<"GAMEDRAW!!!";
}
```

Comment: At which line you got the error?

Comment: This is no Arduino code, but C++ code for a PC. There is no cin or cout for Arduinos

Comment: `if` after main function is not in a function

Comment: Is this even a question? Ir is it simply a post of some random code as "guess where the error is" game? Why are people even putting in any effort to reply when the OP didn't even bother to.put any effort into the errr "question"?

Answer (score 2):

This fragment is outside of a function:

```
if(turn=='X' && draw=0)
{
    cout<<"PLAYER[2] WINS!!!";
}
else if(turn=='O' && draw==0)
{
    cout<<"PLAYER[1] WINS!!!";
}
else
{
    cout<<"GAMEDRAW!!!";
}
```

Some other remarks:

1. Instead of multiple `return` statements, it is better to create a local variable, set it, and return that one at the end. So only use one `return` statement per function (that has a return value).
2. As chrisl mentions: Arduino does not have cin or cout. Use the Serial class for this.
3. You can replace the following code:

> 

```
 switch(choice)
 {
    case 1:row=0; column=0; break;
    case 2:row=0; column=1; break;
    case 3:row=0; column=2; break;
    case 4:row=1; column=0; break;
    case 5:row=1; column=1; break;
    case 6:row=1; column=2; break;
    case 7:row=2; column=0; break;
    case 8:row=2; column=1; break;
    case 9:row=2; column=2; break;
```

by

```
row    = (int) ((choice - 1) / 3);
column =        (choice - 1) % 3;
```

4. Use an enum as return type for function `gameover()`
   E.g. EGameState { Running, PlayerOneWon, PlayerTwoWon, Draw };

   This removes also the global variable `draw`.
5. You call function `gamover` twice, one time within the while loop without checking the result.
6. Do not use a char for the variable `turn` but the player number, or a boolean (XPlayerHasTurn), or an enum.

Comment: For the person downvoting my answer, why?

Comment: 1. it is not Arduino 2. it is only a typo. I think we should apply here on Arduino SE this StackOverflow 'rule' https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252256/behavior-on-questions-caused-by-typographical-errors

Comment: Completely agree with 1, but I don't see what is a typo in this problem (unless you mean it's it's maybe copy/pasted wrongly). It can be easily converted to Arduino though (replacing cin/cout by Serial class calls).

Comment: as an analogy, on the Movies SE a movie identification questions are off-topic. because it was endless count of trivial question

Comment: Ok, so only the remark about cin/cout to Serial class is specific Arduino (but indeed, was not the question itself). Next time I will just make a remark and vote to close.

Comment: as per my comment above why would you put any effort into a "question" where the OP has been extremely lazy to a) seemingly randomly selected Arduino SE when the code is not intended for Arduino, too lazy to actually explain there problem, too lazy to even try to find the typo, too lazy to format the code and probably too lazy to accept your answer +1 for your answer (its a good answer) +2 for @juraj for trying to keep the site clean. -10 (if I could) to OP.